# iOS - How can I keep a view at front when a viewcontroller is presented modally?

Tags: ios, swift, xib, modalviewcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

I have a navigation ViewController and I want to add a custom view named `TestView` on all ViewControllers when the user turns off the internet. I'm adding the custom view to the keyWindow when the internet connectivity status changes. The view is shown and stays there when I push the ViewController but when I present a ViewController modally, the modal ViewController overlays the view.

I want the view to stay at the front even when the VC is presented modally and I want to be able to add some code in my AppDelegate file for all modal ViewControllers or something like that. How can I do this in swift 5? I was thinking if there were a function that's fired every time a modal VC is presented, I could add my code there. Here's how my AppDelegate currently looks like:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, ReachabilityObserverDelegate   {
    var reachability: Reachability?
    var window: UIWindow?
    var internetView: TestView?

    //This is called when the internet connects or disconnects
    func reachabilityChanged(_ isReachable: Bool) { 
        window = getKEYWindow()
        if !isReachable {
            window?.addSubview(internetView!)
        }
        else {
            internetView?.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }

    func getKEYWindow() -> UIWindow? {
        return UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.filter({$0.activationState == .foregroundActive}).map({$0 as? UIWindowScene}).compactMap({$0}).first?.windows.filter({$0.isKeyWindow}).first
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        try? addReachabilityObserver()
        internetView = TestView(frame: CGRect(x:0, y: 50, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: 14))
        return true
    }

}
```

[Main ViewController:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Y0dk.png)

[Internet Turned Off:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0X7RW.png)

[Push ViewController:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gK1Ae.png)

[Present ViewController Modally:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hraos.png)

---

**Update:** I found another way of keeping my view at front. I added the following line `internetView.layer.zPosition = .greatestFiniteMagnitude` in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` and it worked like a charm. Thanks for help everyone.

Comment: how you are presenting a view controller, Storyboard or Code ?

Comment: I would try to create a new UIWindow with almost maximum window level and make it key and visible - it should be on top of your main window :-| (Just a long shot of an idea).

Answer (score 0):

I could suggest one way of doing it:

To open a new UIWindow of higher level and draw it on top of your entire application.

I have no idea if this is the best way of doing it, however I just play tested it with the following code on an empty app - and it seems to work - and even can be transparent.

```
 _myWindow = [[UIWindow alloc]initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds]; 
 [_myWindow makeKeyAndVisible];

 UIViewController* dummyVC = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
 dummyVC.view = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:_myWindow.bounds];
 [dummyVC.view setOpaque:NO]; 
 [dummyVC.view setAlpha:0.1f];

 [_myWindow setRootViewController:dummyVC];
 _myWindow.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelAlert + 1;

 [_myWindow.rootViewController.view.layer setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor].CGColor];
```